# JavaScript onchange event is not firing in IIS7

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, iis-7, onchange

Source Code:

```
<ajaxToolkit:TabContainer ID="tbMBQOutputs" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="720px">
    <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="tbDashboard" runat="server" Height="100%" ToolTip="Dashboard">
    <HeaderTemplate>Dashboard</HeaderTemplate>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upDashboard" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
           <table bgcolor="#E6E6FA" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%; height: 99%; border: solid 1px black; margin-left: 1px; margin-right: 1px;">
           <tr>
               <td>
                    <asp:Panel ID="pnlDashboard_DC" runat="server" GroupingText="Dashboard">
                    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%; height: 99%; border: solid 1px black; margin-left: 1px; margin-right: 1px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                             <asp:Label ID="lblReportCycle_DB" runat="server" Text="Report Cycle"></asp:Label>&emsp;   
                             <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlReportCycle_DB" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Width="140px" CssClass="tb2" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlReportCycle_DB_SelectedIndexChanged" ></asp:DropDownList>
                          </td>
                     </tr>                         
                     <tr>
                          <td align="center">
                               <asp:Label ID="lblMsgDashBoard_DB" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="Green"></asp:Label>
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                 </table>
                 </asp:Panel>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </ContentTemplate>
       </asp:UpdatePanel>
       </ContentTemplate>
       </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
   </ajaxToolkit:TabContainer>
```

JavaScript:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
         function ProgressImage_DashBoard() {
        $('#<%=lblMsgDashBoard_DB.ClientID%>').html("Processing.... Please wait...!!!");
    }
  </script>
```

Code Behind File:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
       ddlReportCycle_DB.Attributes.Add("onchange", "ProgressImage_DashBoard();");
  }
```

This coding is working fine in my system. But when I publish the code in IIS 7, the dropdownlist change event is not at all firing.

But when I comment the code the below code in Page Load Event,

```
//ddlReportCycle_DB.Attributes.Add("onchange", "ProgressImage_DashBoard();");
```

In IIS 7, the dropdownlist change event is working. I need to show the label message during dropdownlist change event. ie Processing. Why this code is not working in IIS 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this, it is working..

Source Code:

```
  <asp:Label ID="lblMsgDashBoard_DB" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="Green"></asp:Label>
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlReportCycle_DB" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Width="140px" CssClass="tb2" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlReportCycle_DB_SelectedIndexChanged" onchange="ShowMsg(this);"></asp:DropDownList>
```

JavaScript:

```
  function ShowMsg(ddl) {            
        var lblMsg = document.getElementById("<%=lblMsgDashBoard_DB.ClientID %>");
        $(lblMsg).html("Processing.... Please wait...!!!");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparantly this is caused by IE configuration for JavaScript. In IIE7 the default configuration is  "disable JavaScript" for certain kind of safety reasons, so you have to enable it.

https://forums.iis.net/t/1150606.aspx